# Need Help Compiling mkbootimg Binary For Android

Tags: android, c

first post new member so if I'm in the wrong section please let me know.

I am trying to compile mkbootimg binary so that I can execute it from the terminal on my android device, I have downloaded the BootTools source from github and compiled it in an backtrack 5 chroot environment, the binaries compiled but when I unpack the boot image and repack it then flash it to my device, upon reboot my device hangs at the boot screen then reboots into recovery.

I have tried this same method on my desktop and the image boots, I have unpacked the image on my device then copied the files over to my desktop and packed them back up with the mkbootimg on my desktop then copied the image to my device and flashed it, the device booted as normal so my guess at that is it must be something to do with the mkbootimg that I compiled has errors or something I am doing wrong, any help is greatly appreciated, thanks Mark.

Answer (score 2):

Probably due to the fact that the endian-ness of the fields in the `struct boot_img_hdr` header varies when compiled for ARM (As compared to the same code compiled for x86). And the boot-loader expects them to be found with the endian-ness that `mkbootimg` compiled for x86 writes them in.

You can compare both the binaries in a hex editor to confirm this.