# Android boot image format

Tags: android, c, bootloader

On Android systems the kernel, the ramdisk, and some metadata are stored in a binary disk image that's handled by the bootloader. Images are built with the `mkbootimg` utility.

Examining the `mkbootimg` source, I see that the image format has a header defined as

```
struct boot_img_hdr {
        unsigned char magic[BOOT_MAGIC_SIZE];

        unsigned kernel_size;  /* size in bytes */
        unsigned kernel_addr;  /* physical load addr */

        unsigned ramdisk_size; /* size in bytes */
        unsigned ramdisk_addr; /* physical load addr */

        unsigned second_size;  /* size in bytes */
        unsigned second_addr;  /* physical load addr */

        unsigned tags_addr;    /* physical addr for kernel tags */
        unsigned page_size;    /* flash page size we assume */
        unsigned unused[2];    /* future expansion: should be 0 */

        unsigned char name[BOOT_NAME_SIZE]; /* asciiz product name */

        unsigned char cmdline[BOOT_ARGS_SIZE];

        unsigned id[8]; /* timestamp / checksum / sha1 / etc */
};
```

without any further qualifications. An instance of this struct is written at the start of the image file with `write`.

Doesn't this embed the endianness and alignment typical of the host system (x86, I believe) in the boot image? Even if the bootloader itself never treats the header as a struct, it seems that running `mkbootimg` on a system with different endianness/alignment (vis Android ARM) would now be problematic.

Am I overestimating how common differences in struct layout are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You are right.

`mkbootimg` cross-compiled for ARM will run into issues as described in this [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15573917/319204).

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the reference.